# how to deploy a vanilla js web application

Tags: javascript, docker, kubernetes, webpack, deployment

, i am creating a the front end part of a project that i am doing and i have some questions about deploying a vanilla js app.

i am using webcomponentes with the shadow dom to create componentes for my project but since i am only using vanilla js - html -css without frameworks i wanna know if is possible to configure a image with docker and then upload that image to a  custom server and deploy it then ? i dont know if you could give me some tips or some documentation on how to do the deploy process of a vanilla app, or how to do the deploy using docker with kubernetes.

Also wanna know if using webpack with babel loader can be of any help  in terms of performance  if i am using only vanilla js with webcomponents.

thanks in advance

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of your solution, it sounds like a multi-stage Dockerfile could do what you want. The first stage would be a Node stage to build the app. The second stage would be a final Nginx image that would be able to serve your app to browsers.

Comment: so is necessary to use node ? or there is a way to deploy the app without node, also would give a look at what you say  thanks for the answer

Comment: There are many ways to do things. You haven't given much info about your app, so it's hard to say if something is 'necessary' or not.

Comment: my web app is just a website build only by using js-html-css using webcomponents but still is only vanilla js no frameworks, in this case do i need to use node to deploy ? or node is needed to deploy the js code and then i can use docker ? sorry if my answer are not clear enought